# Idea code auto-completion slower than eclipse

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea

I'm switched to idea from eclipse recently,the biggest question which make me uncomfortable is the auto popup completion is a little slower then eclipse.

In setting page,i set all possible delay to 0 but it's still slower than eclipse.
And i have noticed that if something(field,method,class...) be reference after first time,it's prompted to be faster,but after a few secends,it's will become slow again,maybe 100~300ms

The eclipse auto-completion is nearly have no delay when i set delay to 0,so how do i raise the speed of idea code auto-completion?

Comment: See https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241235.